# Axios get request is returning user:null using redux actions to make call to the backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, axios

All my axios post requests are working ok.
Also the get request to postman are working fine, but when i make a get request using axios it is returning user:null from the auth middleware from the app.get request.

here is my my files:

```
user.actions file:-

export function auth() {
    const request = 
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001${USER_SERVER}/auth`)
        .then(response => response.data)
    return {
        type: AUTH_USER,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

this is the request in my server file:

```
app.get('/api/users/auth', auth, (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        isAdmin: req.user.role === 0 ? false : true,
        isAuth: true,
        email: req.user.email,
        name: req.user.name,
        lastname: req.user.lastname,
        role: req.user.role,
        cart: req.user.cart,
        history: req.user.history,
        contactnumber: req.user.contactnumber,
        address: req.user.address
    })
})
```

Here is my auth middleware:-

```
const { User } = require('../models/user')

let auth = (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.cookies.x_auth
    User.findByToken(token, (err, user) => {
        if (err)
            throw err
        if (!user)
            return res.json({
                user: user,
                isAuth: false,
                error: true
            })
        console.log(user)
        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()
    })
}

module.exports = { auth }
```

Here is the reducer from my reducer file:

```
case AUTH_USER:
            return { ...state, userData: action.payload }
```

here is my auth.js file where i am making the auth request after signing in 
 from the browser:

```
class AuthCheck extends Component {
        state = {
            loading: false
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.dispatch(auth()).then(Response => {
                console.log(this.props.user)
                let user = this.props.user.userData
                console.log(user)
            })
        }
        render() {
            if (this.state.loading) {
                return (
                    <div className='main_loader'>
                        <Loader size='big' active />
                    </div>
                )
            }
            return (
                <ComposedClass {...this.props} user={this.props.user} />
            )
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            user: state.user
        }
    }
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthCheck)
}
```

The console.log from auth.js file returns:

{user: null, isAuth: false, error: true}

even after i get loginSuccess = true when i login with the registered user.

What is the problem?

Here is my create store file in client's index.js file

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware, ReduxThunk)(createStore);


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(Reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>

    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is my combine reducer file:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import user from './user_reducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that in your reducer file you are setting action.payload to userData but in your component you are accessing as state.user which isn’t right. It should be state.userData

So Change

```
   function mapStateToProps(state) {
       return {
          user: state.user
       }
   }
```

To

```
  function mapStateToProps(state) {
       return {
           user: state.userData
       }
  }
```

So inside render do console.log(this.props.user); you will get the user data

Comment: {user: null, isAuth: false, error: true} .... this is still what i get in my console without any errors!

Comment: I think backend is not the issue as the postman requests returns the user and the user data as well.

Comment: Now it gives a error :Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'userData' of undefined at eval.

Comment: You need to access using this.props.user but not this.props.user.userData

Comment: By using this.props.user , i am getting {userData: {…}}, and in it {user: null, isAuth: false, error: true}.... and i think that is the problem with either axios.get is returning a user null user... or mapStateToProps function usage.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your combineReducers and createStore functions? Also, your authAction function seems a little off. Try this instead:

```
export const auth = () => async dispatch {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001${USER_SERVER}/auth`);            
    dispatch({
        type: AUTH_USER,
        payload: response.data
    })
}
```

Wrap it in a try-catch to handle network errors.